# Confirm box in Activeadmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I am using active admin gem for administration of the users, i have to do some customization in such way that when some admin user update the information i want a confirm box of java script on the show page asking to confirm the updation.

Will someone here kindly put me on the right path and tell me how I can complete my task. I shall be very thankful to all of you.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your submit button is wrapped in `<li class="commit button">`

```
$(function(){
  $('li.commit input').click(function(){
    var response = confirm("YOUR CONFIRMATION MSG");
    if(response){
      return true;
    }

    return false;
  });
}
```

Edit: Just reread your question. Do you mean you want the admin to update the information, then when it's saved and displayed on the show page, the admin needs to confirm?

Comment: yes admin would update the information actually active admin is for administration. i just have to ask him on the show page, just simple confirmation.

Comment: Any reason why you can't just show the confirmation on the edit page? By the time you see the info on the show page, it's already been saved to the database.